# Writing a django login page (With Bootstrap)

Tags: python, django, twitter-bootstrap, authentication

I want to create a login page using django and bootstrap.

My Bootstrap template is:

http://getbootstrap.com/examples/signin/

All things Iv'e found over the internet were about creating a standard login page (without any special design).

Can someone instruct me how to do the authentication and redirection using this bootstrap template(using username except email)?

Thx.

Comment: Login page build with bootstrap: https://medium.com/@m.bilal.social/create-login-page-using-bootstrap-quickly-3993ffeaca15

Answer (score 5):

I found the first 2 answers so inadequate I had to drop my 2 cents in.  You can deploy that login in a few minutes if you know what you're doing.  Create your first app inside your project.  Let's say the app is named "home".  Create a templates directory.  Inside of that, create a "registration" directory.  Create a file "login.html".
Contents of project/home/templates/registration/login.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <link rel="icon" href="../../favicon.ico">
    <title>Signin</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </head>
  <body class="text-center">
    <form class="form-signin">
      <img class="mb-4" src="https://getbootstrap.com/assets/brand/bootstrap-solid.svg" alt="" width="72" height="72">
      <h1 class="h3 mb-3 font-weight-normal">Please sign in</h1>
      <label for="inputEmail" class="sr-only">Email address</label>
      {% csrf_token %}
      <input id="inputEmail" class="form-control" placeholder="Email address" required="" autofocus="" type="email">
      <label for="inputPassword" class="sr-only">Password</label>
      <input id="inputPassword" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required="" type="password">
      <div class="checkbox mb-3">
        <label>
          <input value="remember-me" type="checkbox"> Remember me
        </label>
      </div>
      <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Sign in</button>
      <p class="mt-5 mb-3 text-muted">© 2017-2018</p>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
<style>
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
  padding-top: 40px;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}

.form-signin {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 330px;
  padding: 15px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.form-signin .checkbox {
  font-weight: 400;
}
.form-signin .form-control {
  position: relative;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: auto;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 16px;
}
.form-signin .form-control:focus {
  z-index: 2;
}
.form-signin input[type="email"] {
  margin-bottom: -1px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
}
.form-signin input[type="password"] {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  border-top-left-radius: 0;
  border-top-right-radius: 0;
}
</style>
```

I load jQuery and bootStrap in the headers with a CDN, copied the template into the style tags below (just wanted some code that could be demo'd, I know there are fancier ways to do this).  Basically this is a cut and paste job from the bootstrap website.

Here's the cool magical wand called DRY that django can wave; edit the main urls.py located in the project/project directory:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.contrib.auth.views import LoginView

urlpatterns = [
    path('', LoginView.as_view()),
    path('home/', include('home.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

So why does this work?  Django already wrote the view for you, so all you have to do is drop the template for the view in the right location and then, tada, 24-karat django magic in the air.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using http://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.org/en/latest/crispy_tag_forms.html#bootstrap3-horizontal-forms

```
class SomeForm(forms.Form):
    username = forms.CharField(
        label=u'Username',
        required=True,
    )
    password = forms.CharField(
        label=u'Login',
        required=True,
        widget=forms.PasswordInput
    )
    remember_me = forms.BooleanField(
        label=u'Remember me',
        required=True
    )
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(SomeForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.helper = FormHelper()
        self.helper.form_class = 'form-horizontal'
        self.helper.label_class = 'col-lg-2'
        self.helper.field_class = 'col-lg-8'
        self.helper.layout = Layout(
            'username',
            'password',
            'remember_me',
            StrictButton('Sign in', css_class='btn-default'),

        )
```

Answer (score 0):

Install [django-admin-bootstrapped](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-admin-bootstrapped) and the standard admin login will be styled with Bootstrap.